# " Ce qui a débouché sur l'un ou l'autre scandale". Emploi inusité de l'expression " l'un ou l'autre"

Tags: expressions, anglicismes

Je suis récemment tombé sur cette phase dans un texte  :

" Aux Etats-Unis les formalités de contrôle ont été réduites pour les entreprises chinoises; ce qui a débouché sur l'un ou l'autre scandale".

Les termes ( pronoms?) " l'un" / " l'autre" n'ont pas d'antécédents dans les lignes qui précèdent.

Visiblement cette expression entend signifier " tel ou tel" ( scandale); mais est-elle correcte?

Ne s'agit-il pas d'un anglicisme ( " one or another" ) ? Si c'est le cas, est-il répandu d'après vos observations ?

Merci par avance.

Answer (score 2):

Je n'avais jamais rencontré ce type d'expression en français, mais en cherchant bien, on en trouve des exemples.

> *Le pas que nous allons faire début 2004 va certainement nous positionner différemment sur ce marché même si évidemment, je m'attends **à l'une ou l'autre réaction** de Belgacom. [La Libre Belgique](https://www.lalibre.be/economie/entreprises-startup/colt-veut-titiller-belgacom-sur-le-marche-des-pme-51b8800fe4b0de6db9a93aab),* 2003

Elle est décrite dans des sites de référence:

> *L'une ou l'autre voiture vous sera prêtée au cours de votre séjour en Gaspésie.* [OQLF](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=3840)

et largement discutée aussi sur le blog [Parler français](http://parler-francais.eklablog.com/l-un-et-l-autre-choix-a118118950) qui ne remet pas en cause *l'un ou l'autre + substantif* mais discute du singulier ou du pluriel pour ce dernier, en se référant à l'Académie, au Littré, au Bescherelle et au Bon usage, ce qui écarte les soupçons d'anglicisme.

*L'un ou l'autre* indique un choix, à priori binaire, entre l'un, le premier et l'autre, le second.

Alors que *l'autre* est couramment suivi d'un substantif :

> ...aurait pu déboucher sur l'autre scandale.

on ne trouve pas *l'un* comme choix symétrique :

> ...aurait pu déboucher sur l'un scandale. (??)

Ceci explique que la forme la plus courante est :

> ...de l'un ou l'autre **de ces** scandales.

puisque dans ce cas, il y a bien symétrie :

> ...aurait pu déboucher sur l'un de ces scandales.

> ...aurait pu déboucher sur l'autre de ces scandales.

Il faudrait cependant que les antécédents soient clairs pour le lecteur, ce qui n'est manifestement pas le cas.

*...débouché sur **tel ou tel** scandale* est bien une forme qu'on aurait pu attendre mais cette autre suggestion de @Thélée_Lavoie est plus naturelle :

> ...aurait débouché d'une manière ou d'une autre sur un scandale.

Comment: C'est peut-être pire encore, ça pourrait être _one way or another_ qui se trouverait derrière tout ça, et ce serait alors _d'une manière ou d'une autre_.

Comment: Ca ne veut pas dire qu'il ne s'agit pas d'un anglicisme mais je l'emploie et la rencontre fréquemment de mon côté, dans le sens de "quelques". "Nous partons en vacances en voiture, nous nous attendons à l'un ou l'autre bouchon sur la route", "30 invités ont confirmé, mais j'ai prévu assez de nourriture pour 35 car je m'attends à l'une ou l'autre confirmation de dernière minute",...

Comment: @LaurentS. Un belgicisme aussi peut-être ? Seul hit de google pour cette expression : Patrick Blockx  [je m'attends à l'une ou l'autre réaction de Belgacom](https://www.lalibre.be/economie/entreprises-startup/colt-veut-titiller-belgacom-sur-le-marche-des-pme-51b8800fe4b0de6db9a93aab)

Comment: Oui, peut-être encore un :-) Je n'ai pas trop de problème à trouver cette formule en tout cas [ici](https://www.lesoir.be/art/551495/article/culture/livres/2014-05-22/lapette-nominette-moliere-nouveaux-belgicismes-du-dictionnaire), [ici](https://sitetab2.ac-reims.fr/clg-nouzonville/-spip-/article160.html) (un site bien français), ou encore [là](https://journals.openedition.org/textyles/903). A chaque fois dans le sens "quelque", "un x quelconque",...

Comment: @LaurentS. Oui, c'est plus répandu que je ne le croyais, et on en trouve des exemples très anciens. J'ai largement modifié ma réponse.

Comment: Ouais, vraiment intéressant cet usage-là, ce qui me surprend c'est l'usage indéfini, _un quelconque_, que Laurent explique, comme l'exemple de la BDL si on n'a pas montré ou traité des deux voitures antérieurement. Autrement je dirais plus sponatément _une voiture ou une autre_ pour _quelconque_. Je pense que j'associe la formulation sans antécédent ou indéfinie à un registre littéraire. cc. @LaurentS.